# Why sort order in table makes the View in initial stage in my MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to implement `SortOrder` into my project. There are few issues at this moment

1. If I click on `th` to sort the item, `A-Z` does not change in the first place but item gets sorted. To make `Z-A`, I again has to click on `th` and again it sorts the item.
2. Based on country `USA`, its data has populated in table when page first loads. But the problem is when I change country to `UK` or some other countries. I gets the data from database on these search.
3. Now, I again want to sort `th` but it reloads the whole page and the page goes into initial stage where Country dropdown changes from `UK` to `USA`.

Please guide me. I do not know where I am going wrong. Thank you in advance for your kind help!

Model

```
 public class CountryList
    {
        public int? Country { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountriesList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CountryClass> Lists { get; set; }

    }
    public class CountryClass
    {
        public string NameInfo { get; set; }
        public string AddressInfo { get; set; }

        //Filter DropdownList
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public int? Country { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult CountrySearch(int? country, string sortOrder, string currentFilter)
        {
            CountryList cls = new CountryList();
            CountryData db = new CountryData();
            IEnumerable<CountryClass> data;

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParam = sortOrder == "Name" ? "name_desc" : "Name";
            ViewBag.breedingSortParam = sortOrder == "Address" ? "address_desc" : "Address";

            if (country != null)
            {
                data = db.CountryFilter(country.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                cls.Country = "USA";
                data = db.CountryFilter(country.Value);
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {

                case "Name":
                    data = data.OrderBy(s => s.NameInfo);
                    break;
                case "name_desc":
                    data = data.OrderByDescending(s => s.NameInfo);
                    break;
                case "Address":
                    data = data.OrderBy(s => s.AddressInfo);
                    break;
                case "address_desc":
                    data = data.OrderByDescending(s => s.AddressInfo);
                    break;
                default:
                    data = data.OrderBy(s => s.NameInfo);
                    break;
            }

            CountryList model = new CountryList
            {

            CountriesList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {

            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Nepal" },
             new SelectListItem {Value = "120", Text = "India" },
             new SelectListItem {Value = "121", Text = "USA" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "134", Text = "Australia" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "137", Text = "UK" },
             }, 
                Lists = data
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CountrySearch", "CountrySearch", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Search By
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Country)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountriesList)
            </div>            
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Details
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Name", "CountrySearch", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        <i class="glyphicon @(ViewBag.CurrentSort== "name_desc" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet")"></i>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Address", "CountrySearch", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AddressSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        <i class="glyphicon @(ViewBag.CurrentSort== "address_desc" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet")"></i>
                    </th>

                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Lists)
            {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameInfo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddressInfo)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't approach this like that. Put your table data into a partial view and add a Post action that accepts your model, column to sort and whether its ASC or DEC. and then returns the partial with the sorted model data. Your partial view inclusion needs to be within your form.

Comment: @Wheels73, Can you please provide some coding solutions for this. Appreciates for your help.

Comment: I'll try to put a solution together,

Comment: @Wheels73, Thank you so much.I am looking forward.

Comment: @Wheels73, Currently, If I choose some other country from dropdown and then click on `Search` then it gives me the result. Only problem here is that, if I sort this generated value, it will send me to the original stage by reloading the whole page.

Comment: You might want to consider using an existing framework for this. We are using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/), which will handle the frontend part. As Wheels73 wrote, your backend will still need to respect the sorting information sent by the frontend.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider, Yes, I was looking for solutions which matches to my existing framework. But I am going to give a try which Wheels73 has recommended and will see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, below is an example of how i make a sortable list of countries.

Create the classes required.

```
//Forms view model.
public class CountrySearchViewModel
{
   public int? Country { get; set; }
   public List<CountryClass> CountriesList { get; set; }
   public string CurrentSortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class CountryClass
{
    public string NameInfo { get; set; }
    public string AddressInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Create a main view (CountrySearch) with a form to show the country list which is within a partial view. This uses a form to serialize the form data and a css class to act as a JQuery selector. We then perform an ajax post to sort the data and replace the div contents with the newly sorted data.

```
@model CountrySearchViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="~/Content/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

<script src="~/Content/Scripts/site.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>


<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CountrySearch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmCountries" method="post">
        <div id="divSortedCountries">
            @Html.Partial("_SortedCountryData", Model)
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script>

    $(document).on('click', '.sortable-link', function () {
        var formData = $("#frmCountries").serialize();
        var sortUrl = $(this).data('sorturl');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: sortUrl,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divSortedCountries").html(data); 
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<style>
    .sortable-link {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Add Controller method to return the view.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult CountrySearch()
 {
    var model = new CountrySearchViewModel();

    //This list should come from a service?!
    var listOfCountries = new List<CountryClass>()
    {
        new CountryClass(){NameInfo ="Nepal", AddressInfo = "9 Street1 YourTown YourCountry"},
        new CountryClass(){NameInfo ="India", AddressInfo = "9 Street1 YourTown YourCountry"},
        new CountryClass(){NameInfo ="USA", AddressInfo = "9 Street1 YourTown YourCountry"},
        new CountryClass(){NameInfo ="Australia", AddressInfo = "9 Street1 YourTown YourCountry"},
        new CountryClass(){NameInfo ="UK", AddressInfo = "9 Street1 YourTown YourCountry"},
     };

    model.CountriesList = listOfCountries;
    model.CurrentSortOrder = "ASC";

    return View("CountrySearch", model);
}
```

Create a partial view ("_SortedCountryData") which will show your sorted data. Note that here I have used TextBoxFor. This is to ensure that your model binds to the controls so we are able to post back the list to sort. You could of course build up the list each time from a separate service that returns you a list of countries as per my comment in the CountySearch "Get"

```
@model CountrySearchViewModel

        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Details
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th><a class="sortable-link" data-sorturl="/Test/SortCountryData?columnToSort=Name&sortOrder=@Model.CurrentSortOrder">Country Name</a></th>
                    </tr>s
                    @for (int counter = 0; counter <= Model.CountriesList.Count -1; counter++) 
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h4>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.CountriesList[counter].NameInfo, null, new{@class="form-control"})</h4> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Add the method to return the partial view and the method to sort the data.

```
public PartialViewResult SortCountryData(CountrySearchViewModel model, string columnToSort, string sortOrder)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            model.CountriesList = ReturnSortedCountries(model.CountriesList, columnToSort, sortOrder);
            model.CurrentSortOrder = sortOrder == "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";

            return PartialView("_SortedCountryData", model);
        }

        public List<CountryClass> ReturnSortedCountries(List<CountryClass> countryList, string columnToSort, string order)
        {
            List<CountryClass> sortedData;

            switch (columnToSort)
            {
                case "Name":
                    sortedData = order == "ASC" ? countryList.OrderBy(s => s.NameInfo).ToList() : countryList.OrderByDescending(s => s.NameInfo).ToList();
                    break;

                case "Address":
                    sortedData = order == "ASC" ? countryList.OrderBy(s => s.AddressInfo).ToList() : countryList.OrderByDescending(s => s.AddressInfo).ToList();
                    break;

                default:
                    sortedData = countryList.OrderBy(s => s.NameInfo).ToList();
                    break;
            }

            return sortedData;
        }
```

I've test this locally and it works.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry to ask you one help. Can you please invite me for chat. I want to share you my code. I am not getting the solution. Please help me.

Comment: Can't at the moment, i'm at work sorry!. edit your question with your current code and I'll take a look when possible.

Comment: I have added another question related to this. Please have a look and also please provide me solution.[please check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152891/sorting-table-row-redirects-the-whole-page-in-my-mvc-application)