# Sorting table row redirects the whole page in my MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to sort table row by clicking on its `th` but it is not working in my application. When I click on `th` it redirects the whole page and reloads it.

I want to sort the table row without rendering the whole page. Please guide me.

I have added all the code. Anyone please help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Model

```
  public class clsEmployee
    {
        public int? Country { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountriesList { get; set; }

        public int Department { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }

    }
    public class clsEmployeeClass
    {
       public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
      [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Employee()
        {
            clsEmployee emp = new clsEmployee();
            emp = DropdownList();
            emp.Country = 1;
            emp.Department = 2;
            return View(emp);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Employee(clsEmployee model, string sortOrder, string currentFilter)
        {
            model = DropdownList();
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.EmpIdSortParam = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "empid_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.NameSortParam = sortOrder == "Name" ? "name_desc" : "Name";
            ViewBag.AddressSortParam = sortOrder == "Address" ? "address_desc" : "Address";
            ViewBag.SalarySortParam = sortOrder == "Salary" ? "salary_desc" : "Salary";
            return View(model);

        }

        public clsEmployee DropdownList()
        {
            var model = new clsEmployee
            {            
                CountriesList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
             new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "India" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Sri Lanka" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Pakistan" },
             new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "USA" },
            },
                Departments = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
             new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text="Finance", Selected=true },
             new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "IT" },
             new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Sales" },
            }


            };
            return model;

        }

        public void EmployeeSearchonFilter(clsEmployee model)
        {
            clsUtilities clsUtilities = new clsUtilities();
            DataSet ds;
            List<clsEmployeeClass> leadingSiresClass = new List<clsEmployeeClass>();
            string SqlStatement;
            SqlParameter[] paramneters = new SqlParameter[2];
            SqlStatement = "exec GetEmployeeDetails @Country,@Department";
            paramneters[0] = new SqlParameter("@Country", SqlDbType.Int);
            paramneters[0].Value = model.Country;
            paramneters[1] = new SqlParameter("@Department", SqlDbType.Int);
            paramneters[1].Value = model.Department;
            ds = clsUtilities.CommandParams(SqlStatement, paramneters);
            DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
            ViewData["Employee"] = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        public ActionResult EmployeeFilter(clsEmployee model)
        {
            EmployeeSearchonFilter(model);
            return PartialView("~/Views/Employee/_EmployeePartial.cshtml", ViewData["Employee"]);
        }
```

Employee View

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Employee", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "EmployeeReport" }))
        {
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayName("Country")</b>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountriesList)
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.DisplayName("Department")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, Model.Departments)
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button type="button" id="Search">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="EmployeePartial">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_EmployeePartial partial View

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("EmpId", "Employee", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.EmpIdSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter})
                <i class="glyphicon @(ViewBag.CurrentSort== "empid_desc" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-order")"></i>
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Employee", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                <i class="glyphicon @(ViewBag.CurrentSort== "name_desc" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet")"></i>
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Address", "Employee", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AddressSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                <i class="glyphicon @(ViewBag.CurrentSort== "address_desc" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet")"></i>
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Salary", "Employee", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SalarySortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                <i class="glyphicon @(ViewBag.CurrentSort== "salary_desc" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-order")"></i>
            </th>           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @if (ViewData["Employee"] != null)
    {
        var dt = ViewData["Employee"] as System.Data.DataTable;
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @dr["EmpId"]
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @dr["Name"]
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @dr["Address"]
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @dr["Salary"]
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    }

</table>
```

Scripts inside Employee View

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         PartialViewUpdate();
    });

    function PartialViewUpdate() {
        var partial = $('#EmployeePartial');
        var form = $('#EmployeeReport');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EmployeeFilter", "Employee")',
                type: 'Post',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    partial.html(data);
                }

            });
    };

    $('#Search').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var partial = $('#EmployeePartial');
        var form = $('#EmployeeReport');
          $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Employee", "Employee")',
                type: 'Post',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    PartialViewUpdate();
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: use DataTable jquery library

Comment: @ParthShah, can you please show me how to use it.

Comment: @MVC - You've not implemented the solution I gave you?! You have no partial view in your main Employee view? and you still appear to be using ViewBag when you should be using your models?

Comment: @Wheels73, Sorry, I tried to implement your solution but could not able to implement that. Appreciated if you could provide solutions for this. I am new to programming so do not have much ideas. Please help me. There is partial view inside main `Employee` View. I am loading partial view using JQuery and its Id is `EmployeePartial`.

Comment: @MVC - Sorry.. but I don't understand what you are doing now. I've put your posted code into a solution and you now seem to have a country drop and a department drop down with a search button... countries belong to the employees model and so do departments? Can you say what your end goal is please? Are you trying to search for all employees in a country and department and then order those results by clicking on the table header row?

Comment: "When I click on th it redirects the whole page and reloads it."...that's because the HTML.ActionLink helper you added with each th creates a regular hyperlink, the kind you click on in any webpage to take you to another page. If you don't want that, then either don't use hyperlinks, or use JavaScript to suppress the default behaviour (using "preventDefault", you can google it) and do some other task instead.

Comment: @Wheels73, Sorry for disturbing you many times. Yes, I have country and department  dropdowns with search button. If I select any country and department and then if click on search then it gives me employees details who belongs to those category. As you said, I want to reorder those results without post back to the server. Otherwise, it will reloads everything even dropdown lists. Please suggest me.

Comment: @ADyson, can you please suggest me what to use instead of ActionLink. And if I will use ActionLink then how to suppress the post. I understand that `preventDefault` will stop reloading the page but other than this, what to write in JQuery. Please help.

Comment: well you could use a normal button and just hang a "click" event from that. Or just put text directly in your th and put the "click" event against the th. Pretty much any element can be made clickable, without causing postbacks. After that, apart from initiating some kind of search, it's not really clear what your intentions are. perhaps you need to make a new AJAX request to the server to send back the data in a different order?

Comment: Or you could just use one of the many ready-made JS table plugins available for free online, which come with searching/sorting/filtering/paging functionality built-in. FooTable, DataTables, jsGrid, the list is endless, you can easily search for them. Most will support server-side processing of data as well if you need it.

Comment: @ADyson, Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, I want to reorders the table data row. Suppose I click on Name `th` then it should sort in  either ascending or descending order and same way for `Address` and others. Appreciated if you provide some solutions for this. I am trying since morning but got stuck here.

Comment: @ADyson, Actually, I do not want to use library for this. I think it overloads the process. So please provide me some simple and elegant solutions for this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @ADyson, Please help me. I am struggling to find the solutions.

Comment: @Wheels73, If possible then can you please provide solutions for this. I am looking for this since morning and tried many different ways but no luck. please help me.

Comment: "I think it overloads the process"...actually probably those guys have spent time getting the most efficient solution already. They have honed their products over many hours and using many experienced developers. Why re-invent the wheel, unless you have an academic interest in studying that particular topic? Besides you're already using several other "libraries" such as jQuery, MVC, Razor, all the other .NET stuff. Then there's all the Windows libraries under that, etc etc. If you really want to be library-free then start learning Assembly language...

Comment: @MVC - I'm working on it... I'll try to give it you soon!

Comment: @ADyson, Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Wheels73, Thank you so much for your patience and doing this. I am really thank to you.

Comment: @MVC - I've posted my answer. I've spent more time that I would like normally so you'll have to take it from here! cheers

Comment: @Wheels73, Thank you so much. You made my day. Sure, I will take it from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK as discussed, I've taken what you've got so far and made it work, but with changes!

Code

```
 public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult EmployeeSearch()
        {
            var model = ReturnViewModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        public EmployeeViewModel ReturnViewModel()
        {
            var model = new EmployeeViewModel()
            {
                CountriesList = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "India" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Sri Lanka" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Pakistan" },
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "USA" }
                },
                Departments = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text="Finance", Selected=true },
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "IT" },
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Sales" },
                }
            };

            model.CurrentSearchOrder = "ASC";
            model.EmployeesFound= new List<Employee>();

            return model;
        }


        public PartialViewResult TestEmployeeSearchService(EmployeeViewModel model)
        {
            //Simulated service - I presume you have list of employees somewhere.
            var list = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee() {EmpId =1, Name = "John Smith", Address="1 MyStreet MyTown", CountryID = 4, DepartmentID = 2,Salary= 30000},   // - I.T.
                new Employee() {EmpId= 2, Name = "Chander Deepak", Address="9 MyRoad MyVillage", CountryID = 1, DepartmentID = 1, Salary = 30000} ,   //India - Finance
                new Employee() {EmpId = 3, Name = "Pritesh Shah", Address="20 MyRoad MyVillage", CountryID = 1, DepartmentID = 1, Salary = 35000}    //India - Finance
            };

            //Employees matching countryid
            var employeesInCountry = list.Where(e => e.CountryID == model.CountryID).ToList();

            //Department ID
            model.EmployeesFound = model.DepartmentID != 0 ? employeesInCountry.Where(e => e.DepartmentID == model.DepartmentID).ToList() : employeesInCountry;

            return PartialView("_EmployeePartial", model);
        }

        public PartialViewResult SortEmployeeData(EmployeeViewModel model, string columnToSort, string sortOrder)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            model.EmployeesFound = ReturnSortedEmployees(model.EmployeesFound, columnToSort, sortOrder);
            model.CurrentSearchOrder = sortOrder == "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";

            return PartialView("_EmployeePartial", model);
        }

        public List<Employee> ReturnSortedEmployees(List<Employee> countryList, string columnToSort, string order)
        {
            List<Employee> sortedData;

            switch (columnToSort)
            {
                case "EmpID":
                    sortedData = order == "ASC" ? countryList.OrderBy(s => s.EmpId).ToList() : countryList.OrderByDescending(s => s.EmpId).ToList();
                    break;

                case "Name":
                    sortedData = order == "ASC" ? countryList.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList() : countryList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name).ToList();
                    break;

                case "Address":
                    sortedData = order == "ASC" ? countryList.OrderBy(s => s.Address).ToList() : countryList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Address).ToList();
                    break;

                case "Salary":
                    sortedData = order == "ASC" ? countryList.OrderBy(s => s.Salary).ToList() : countryList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Salary).ToList();
                    break;


                default:
                    sortedData = countryList.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
                    break;
            }

            return sortedData;
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountriesList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }

        public List<Employee> EmployeesFound { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        public string CurrentSearchOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public int? CountryID { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Main Employee view

```
@model EmployeeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeSearch";
}

@{ Layout = null; }

<script src="~/Content/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

<h2>Employee Search</h2>

<div class="col-md-2">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "EmployeeReport" }))
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <b>@Html.DisplayName("Country")</b>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, Model.CountriesList)
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Department")
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentID, Model.Departments)
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="button" id="Search">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="divEmployees">
            @Html.Partial("_EmployeePartial", Model)
        </div>


      }


    </div>

<style>
    .sortable-link {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<script>

    $(document).on('click', '.sortable-link', function () {
        var formData = $("#EmployeeReport").serialize();
        var sortUrl = $(this).data('sorturl');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: sortUrl,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divEmployees").html(data); 
            }
        });
    });

    $('#Search').click(function () {
        var form = $('#EmployeeReport');

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TestEmployeeSearchService", "Employee")',
            type: 'Post',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divEmployees").html(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Partial view

```
@model EmployeeViewModel

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        <a class="sortable-link" data-sorturl="/Employee/SortEmployeeData?columnToSort=EmpID&sortOrder=@Model.CurrentSearchOrder">ID</a>
        <span class="glyphicon @(Model.CurrentSearchOrder == "DESC" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-order")"></span>
    </th>

    <th>
        <a class="sortable-link" data-sorturl="/Employee/SortEmployeeData?columnToSort=Name&sortOrder=@Model.CurrentSearchOrder">Name</a>
        <span class="glyphicon @(Model.CurrentSearchOrder == "DESC" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-order")"></span>
    </th>

    <th>
        <a class="sortable-link" data-sorturl="/Employee/SortEmployeeData?columnToSort=Address&sortOrder=@Model.CurrentSearchOrder">Address</a>
        <span class="glyphicon @(Model.CurrentSearchOrder == "DESC" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-order")"></span>
    </th>

    <th>
        <a class="sortable-link" data-sorturl="/Employee/SortEmployeeData?columnToSort=Salary&sortOrder=@Model.CurrentSearchOrder">Salary</a>
        <span class="glyphicon @(Model.CurrentSearchOrder == "DESC" ? "glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt" : "glyphicon-sort-by-order")"></span>
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>

    @for (int counter = 0; counter <= Model.EmployeesFound.Count -1; counter++) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeesFound[counter].EmpId, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeesFound[counter].Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.EmployeesFound[counter].Address, null, new{@class="form-control"})
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.EmployeesFound[counter].Salary, null, new{@class="form-control"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>      
@Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.CurrentSearchOrder)
```

Please look at the separation of the main view from the partial and how the Links to the Sort method are constructed and selected via JQuery. STOP using ViewBag and use models for your views. Its MVC! where M = Model.. not viewbag!

all the best

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and the solution you provided. I want to use `@Html.DisplayFor` instead of  `@Html.TextBoxFor`.

Comment: If I use `@Html.DisplayFor` then `model.EmployeesFound` inside `SortEmployeeData` function gets null. But if it is Textbox then it passes the value. can you please suggest me why.

Comment: @MVC - If you look at the HTML generated by TextBoxFor and DisplayFor, you will notice that the display does not have an id! This is because is just displays and therefore does not bind to the model when posted. use a textbox and style it with css to look how you need it too.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution.It really helped me.